# Java/JS/JSTL - how to get property from javabean/display error message

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

In my html, I need a property from my bean and store it in a variable - how can I do this?

What I'm trying to do is, display an error message when a user's login fail - I know I can do this with javascript, but I don't know how I can "call" this javascript to load when a login is unsuccessful.

Many ways to do this.. but I don't know how to do any of them.

Comment: Your question lacks **context**. Are you using JSP? JSF? `___`?

Comment: In the future, please formulate your question and choose the tags carefully :)

Answer (score 1):

Like HTML and CSS, JS is part of template text. Just let JSP print it as if it is a JS variable.

```
<script>var foo = '${bean.foo}';</script>
```

You just need to make sure that the generated HTML looks the way so that JS understands it.

```
<script>var foo = 'bar';</script>
```

With JSP/JSTL/EL you can control the output whatever way you want. You can use JSTL `<c:if>` to print it conditionally. You can use EL conditional operator `${condition ? printIfTrue : printIfFalse }` to toggle output based on a condition. Etcetera.

#### See also:

- [Communication between Java/JSP/JSF and JavaScript](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use @BalusC's way, but if you don't want to place `<script>` tag in your JSP code, one option is to set the value as a hidden field:-

```
<input id="foo" type="hidden" value="${bean.foo}" />
```

Then, in your javascript, do this:-

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo").value;
```